# Function not returning number

Tags: functions, manipulate, replacement

I am quite new to *Mathematica* and I guess this question is really basic, but I can't figure it out myself.
I'm making a simple notebook that plots a Hamiltonian function, a plane of constant energy, and the phase space of the system. I highlight the intersection of the plane and the Hamiltonian, and I would like that the highlighted curve would show up as a red orbit in the phase plane. This is my code:

```
H[q_, p_, a_] := a q p + p^3 + q^2;

Qdot[q_, p_, a_] := Derivative[0, 1, 0][H][q, p, a];
Pdot[q_, p_, a_] := -Derivative[1, 0, 0][H][q, p, a];

Const[E_] := E;

Pbar[q_, a_, E_] := Evaluate[NSolve[H[q, p, a] == E, p, Reals]];

Manipulate[
    {
        ContourPlot3D[{H[q, p, a] == z, Const[E] == z}, {q, -qext, 
    qext}, {p, -pext, pext}, {z, -zext, zext}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {0 &, 0 &, Const[E] - H[#1, #2, a] &}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 60]]],
        StreamPlot[{Qdot[q, p, a], Pdot[q, p, a]}, {q, -qext, 
    qext}, {p, -pext, pext}, 
   StreamPoints -> {{200, {{qbar, Pbar[qbar, a, E]}, {Red, Thick}}}, 
     0.1, 10}]
    },
    {E, -5, 5},
    {a, -10, 10},
    {qbar, -1, 1},
    {qext, 1, 5},
    {pext, 1, 5},
    {zext, 0.01, 5}
 ]
```

So the problem is with `Pbar`: it is a function, so it returns `p -> _number_`, not `_number_`. I need it to return the number, because that way `StreamPlot` will highlight the streamline starting from `{qbar, Pbar[qbar, a,E]}`

Comment: No not really, but this is quite irrelevant to the question.

Comment: take a look at [NSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

Comment: The answer can be found as [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193) to our giant Pifalls question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: In V10, you can use `Values@NSolve[..]`.

Comment: The difficulty lies in `StreamPoints`, not in the replacement rules only. `Pbar` must be a number without braces. `Part` must be added if you use `Values`. `Values@NSolve[ .. ][[1, 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with few **new** edits:

```
H[q_, p_, a_] := a q p + p^3 + q^2; 
Qdot[q_, p_, a_] := Derivative[0, 1, 0][H][q, p, a]; 
Pdot[q_, p_, a_] := -Derivative[1, 0, 0][H][q, p, a];
const[e_] := e; 
Pbar[q_, a_, e_] := p /. First@NSolve[H[q, p, a] == e, p, Reals];

Manipulate[
{ContourPlot3D[{H[q, p, a] == z, const[e] == z}, {q, -qext, qext}, {p, -pext, pext}, {z, -zext, zext}, 
MeshFunctions -> {0 &, 0 &, const[e] - H[#1, #2, a] &}, 
MeshStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 60]]], 

 StreamPlot[{Qdot[q, p, a], Pdot[q, p, a]}, {q, -qext,qext}, {p, -pext, pext}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{200, {{qbar, Pbar[qbar, a, e]}, {Red, Thick}}},0.1, 10}]},
 {e, -5, 5}, {a, -10, 10}, {qbar, -1, 1}, {qext, 1, 5}, {pext, 1, 5}, {zext, 0.01, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works outside of manipulate, e.g. if I write `Pbar[2,4,1]` it outputs `{-0.368733}` but it doesn't work in the `Manipulate`! Why is that so?

Comment: The code works fine for me, Windows 10x64, Mathematica 10.3.1

Comment: Does it highlight in red  the streamline that corresponds to the intersection of the plane and the Hamiltonian? Because it never does, for me. My guess is that since there is not one unique solution to the intersection, it cannot work

Comment: Nothing red in Mathematica 10 on Win10

Comment: As has already been said, the code runs fine (not the red streamline). First I would check the function of StreamPlot without Manipulate.

Comment: Ok now my problem is to figure out how to get `StreamPlot` to accept `Pbar`. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Leonardo it is Christmastime! Your code runs fine!